# Запись в MySQL в разные таблицы

Tags: mysql, python, sql, парсер

Я парсю сайт. Мне нужно распарсить 2 категории Fresh и Bekery и занести данные в БД. Когда запускаю скрипт, то все данные с обоих категорий заносятся в обе таблицы в БД. А мне нужно, чтобы товары с Fresh занеслись в таблицу fresh, а товары Bekery в таблицу bekery, по отдельности.

Python-код

```
import re
import requests
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import MySQLConnection, Error
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


class DataBase:
    def __init__(self, user, password, db):
        self.user = user
        self.password = password
        self.db = db
        try:
            conn = self.get_conn()
            # if conn.is_connected():
            #     print('Подключение прошло успешно.')
        except Error as e:
            print(e)

    def get_conn(self):
        conn = mysql.connector.connect(user=self.user,
                                       password=self.password,
                                       db=self.db)
        return conn

    def add_products(self, title, price, url):
        try:
            sql_fresh = 'INSERT INTO tesco.fresh (title, price, url) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)'
            sql_bakery = 'INSERT INTO tesco.bakery (title, price, url) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)'
            args = (title, price, url)
            conn = self.get_conn()
            c = conn.cursor()
            c.execute(sql_fresh, args)
            c.execute(sql_bakery, args)
            conn.commit()
        except Error as e:
            print(e)


def write_database(data):
    db = DataBase('root', '123456', 'tesco')
    db.add_products(data['title'], data['price'], data['url'])


class Tesco:
    def get_html(self, url):
        r = requests.get(url)
        return r.text

    def get_total_pages(self, html):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
        total_pages = \
            soup.find('nav', class_='pagination--page-selector-wrapper').find_all('a', class_='pagination--button')[
                -2].find('span').text

        return int(total_pages)

    def get_page_data(self, html):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
        products = soup.find('div', class_='product-lists').find_all('li', class_='product-list--list-item')

        for product in products:
            try:
                offer = product.find('div', class_='yellow-square').text
            except:
                offer = ''

            if len(offer) == 0:
                try:
                    title = product.find('div', class_='product-details--content').find('a',
                                                                                        class_='product-tile--title').text
                except:
                    title = ''

                try:
                    price = float(product.find('div', class_='controls').find('span', class_='value').text)
                except:
                    price = ''

                try:
                    url = 'https://www.tesco.com' + product.find('div', class_='product-details--content').find('a',
                                                                                                                class_='product-tile--title').get(
                        'href')
                except:
                    url = ''

                data = {
                    'title': title,
                    'price': price,
                    'url': url
                }

                write_database(data)


def main():
    tesco = Tesco()

    base_url_fresh = 'https://www.tesco.com/groceries/en-GB/shop/fresh-food/all?offset='
    base_url_bakery = 'https://www.tesco.com/groceries/en-GB/shop/bakery/all?offset='

    print('Записываю Fresh.')
    for i in range(0, 2):
        print((i / 2) * 100)
        current_page = i * 24
        url_gen = base_url_fresh + str(current_page)
        html = tesco.get_html(url_gen)
        tesco.get_page_data(html)

    print('Записываю Bakery.')
    for i in range(0, 2):
        print((i / 2) * 100)
        current_page = i * 24
        url_gen = base_url_bakery + str(current_page)
        html = tesco.get_html(url_gen)
        tesco.get_page_data(html)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Фото с комментарием**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def add_products(self, title, price, url):
    try:
       sql_fresh = 'INSERT INTO tesco.fresh (title, price, url) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)'
       sql_bakery = 'INSERT INTO tesco.bakery (title, price, url) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)'
       args = (title, price, url)
       conn = self.get_conn()
       c = conn.cursor()
       c.execute(sql_fresh, args)
       c.execute(sql_bakery, args)
       conn.commit()
    except Error as e:
       print(e)
```

В данной процедуре одновременно заносятся данные в обе таблицы:

---

```
sql_fresh = 'INSERT INTO tesco.fresh (title, price, url) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)'
sql_bakery = 'INSERT INTO tesco.bakery (title, price, url) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)'
```

Если не ошибаюсь, должно быть так:

```
def add_products(self, t_name, title, price, url):
    try:
       sql ="INSERT INTO {0} (title, price, url) VALUES('{1}', {2}, '{3}')".format(t_name, title, price, url)
       #print(sql)
       conn = self.get_conn()
       c = conn.cursor()
       c.execute(sql)
       conn.commit()
    except Error as e:
       print(e)
```

Где `t_name` параметр - название таблицы `(tesco.bakery, tesco.fresh)`

Comment: Хороший способ, спасибо! Единственно, у меня не получается передать t_name. Я передаю как строку и при записи компилятор ругается, говоря, что ошибка в синтаксисе при передаче данных SQL

Comment: я проверю сейчас

Comment: @Валерий отредактировал процедуру, с функцией format будет более наглядна замена параметров в строке SQL запроса, обратите внимание на наличие кавычек для параметра title и url

Comment: @Валерий получилось?

Comment: Да, спасибо большое!)

Comment: @Валерий Отлично, успехов!